# Access to class variable in setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a JavaScript class that has to publish events every so often. The code looks like this :

```
class TimerService {
  constructor(BroadcastService) {
    this.Broadcast = BroadcastService;
    this.timeout;
    this.warningTimer;
    this.startTimer();
  }

  startTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    clearTimeout(this.warningTimer);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.startWarning, 30000);
  }

  startWarning() {
    this.Broadcast.send("timeout-warning");
    this.warningTimer = setTimeout(this.logout, 60000);
  }

  logout() {
    this.Broadcast.send("session-expired");
  }
}

export default { service: TimerService, name: "TimerService" };
```

The issue is, in the setTimeout calllback functions, the `this` scope points to `window` so I am not able to access `this.Broadcast`. What is the best way to structure this so I have access to everything I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use these 2 approaches. I think first is the best if you have nothing to do with function own context and it is more preferable approach.

1) [**Arrow function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - `this.timeout = setTimeout(() => this.startWarning(), 30000);`

2) [**Explicit Context binding**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) - `this.timeout = setTimeout(this.startWarning.bind(this), 30000);`